# What is the meaning of "in particular" in this proof?

Tags: logic

This is the context:

> In other words, P says
>
> “This logical sentence does not have a proof shorter than n.”
>
> or
>
> “I do not have a short proof.”
>
> We call such a logical sentence a Parikh sentence.
>   Let us determine if this sentence is true or false. If P were false then a (short) proof
>   of P does exist. But how can there be a proof of a false statement within a consistent
>   system? So the sentence is not false and must be true. As we saw above with Gödel’s
>   incompleteness theorem, just because a statement is true, does not mean it is
>   provable. Now let’s consider the following relatively short proof that a (long) proof
>   of the Parikh sentence exists:
>
> If the Parikh sentence does not have a proof, then ***in particular*** it does not have a short proof. Then
>   we can easily check all proofs less than n and see that none of them prove P. Summing up: if the
>   sentence cannot be proved, then we can prove it.
>
> Source: The Outer Limits of Reason: What Science, Mathematics, and Logic Cannot Tell Us
>   by Noson S. Yanofsky

This is about Parikh’s Theorem. The problem I am having, because I am not a native speaker, is with "in particular" part. Does it mean "specially"? Or does it mean "definitely/certainly"? Or does it mean something else completely? Because I Don't get it how "specially" can apply to this sentence. If this is not a good question for this forum, Tell me to remove it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "in particular" means you are going from a more general statement to a less general statement.

Comment: Yes [especially](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/in%20particular)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know "a fortiori"?

It's the "a maiore ad minus" argument, concluding from a general to a more special ("particular") case. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_a_fortiori

As in:

"All cats are mammals. *In particular*, all black cats are mammals."

Answer (score 3):

A red shirt is a 'particular' or 'specific* kind of shirt.

So, I could say:

"If I don't wear a shirt, then in particular I don't wear a red shirt"

This is just like the:

"If there is no proof, then in particular there is no short proof"

Answer (score 1):

The usage of "n particular" in those contexts means that we made some general assumption or observation (such as "no proof at all"), which logically entails a more specific observation (such as "no short proof"), and this more specific case is the one we're interested in.